# What is the best way to create a pop-out menu grid similar to Gmail's in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Gmail has the grid icon that turns into a pop out menu like so:

[image: Gmail pop out]

I want to implement the exact same thing. I already have the grid icon as a button in my nav.

I was looking at [Modals](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), but I've had trouble figuring out how to make the modal stay "attached" to the button when clicked and the window resized. Is there a quick implementation of this someone can explain to me?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have anything quite like this built-in.

Comment: If you're having trouble keeping the modal attached to the button you could make the modal a child of the button, make the button's `position:relative` and the modal's `position:absolute`. That way the modal's position stay be relative to the button.

Comment: I would use a Dropdown or a Popover with some custom styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to customize the [Dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns), like this. I think it's a good start.

```css
.dropdown-menu .item {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu row">
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-4">
      ICON
      <strong>Name</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```